# Sample Example of Authentication and Authorization using XACML policy, wso2is-5.1, wso2esb-4.9 and wso2as-5.3

Tags: authorization, xacml, abac, wso2-identity-server

I am new to wso2 environment. I am doing a sample application for authentication and authorization using wso2 technologies. On http://wso2.com/library/articles/, i found same sample application but these sample application are based on older version of wso2 software.

I am using XACML-3.0, wso2is-5.1, wso2esb-4.9 and  wso2as-5.3 for my application. I am getting mainly configuration problem.

If anyone have sample application or know link, where i can get, Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain the requirement more? What kind of app is acting as a PEP? We can use WSO2 IS as authentication and authorization provider for a Web app or ESB Proxy/API. Based on those, your use case may differ. 
Also please mention the errors you face and what you tried already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Balana the XACML engine that is used by WSO2 Identity server internally. You can use Balana as a java library in your applications for XACML based access control. We have a few code samples[1] that you can have a look at.

The other option is to use the entitlement service provided by WSO2 Identity Server. So basically you need a PEP client to send XACML requests to the entitlement service and get the response from the server. Please have a look at [2] for details on how to achieve this.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/balana/tree/master/modules/balana-samples

[2] http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/06/14/pep-client-for-wso2is-pdp/